# Special characters escaping with queryType: full

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am having issues while searching for terms with special charachters in it with queryType set to full.
Take this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#escaping-special-characters

If I use:

```
{
  "search": "https\:\/\/*",
  "queryType": "full",
  "highlight": "content"
}
```

I get the error `FieldNotSearchable: Illegal arguments in query request: https is not a searchable field.`
This means that it's using `https:` as a field selector.
Can someone explain too me why it's not excaping the `:`?

If I use

```
{
  "search": "https\:\/\/*",
  "queryType": "simple",
  "highlight": "content"
}
```

I got empty results, which is what I'm expecting

Answer (score 0):

In the `full` queryType, the `\` used does not escape the `:` character and is considered a **Fielded search**. It interprets it as `https://` and gives an error, stating it is not searchable since you don't have `https` field. Refer to the documentation below for more information on **Fielded search**:

[Lucene query syntax - Azure AI Search | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_fields)

In the `simple` queryType, the **Fielded search** is not considered, and it searches for the entire string.

You can see the difference in results when searching for the field named `street`:

`simple`

[image]

`full`

[image]

In `simple`, it returns results for the word "street," but in `full`, it searches for the word "red" in the field `street`.

Therefore, in the `full` queryType, you need to use `\\` to escape the characters.

```json
{
  "search": "street\\:red",
  "queryType": "full",
  "highlight": "street"
}
```

This should return results for the word "street" since the `:` is escaped.

[image]

Searching for `https\\:\\/\\/*` will yield empty results.

[image]